# Insert data from the request to the Model (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

This is the Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class UserModel extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

I'm trying to save the data with that:

```
UserModel::create($data);
```

This is the error I got:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `users` () values ()) in file \src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 822

The value of $data is on the screenshot

I want to insert directly, without giving everytime all the parameters, the rows in the table, but seems that the model can't catch the query parameters
[image]

Comment: Just based on the error, you are not inserting ANY data. Can you share the full error? And do not share images of code, share literal text

Comment: Maybe show how `$data` is built or `dd($data)`

Comment: where did you call this `UserModel::create($data);` ? show us your controller

Answer (score 0):

Some how your data variable is empty or it does not contains value in 'name' key.

Normally we do

```php
$data = $request->all();  // request contains all the required data.

UserModel::create($data);
```

Please show us your full controller code.

Comment: This has to be a comment... wait for him to reply to our comments

Comment: ops Okay -> I don't know that